# Can't connect to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) Device Portal in UWP by HttpClient or else (Windows 10 Mobile RS1 only)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I want to make apps to implement [REST API's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#remote-control) in Device Portal into my apps. But, I can't connect to 127.0.0.1 with HttpClient and another API's smiliar like that even in System.Net and Windows.Web.Http , always got exception "connection with the server could not be established" .

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIAMD.png)

But, It's ONLY happen in RS1 build (104393) . In TH2 build (10568) anything work like charm.

Here's my code:

when i use `Windows.Web.Http`

```
private async void dvInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("*/*");
                string ResponseString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/api/os/machinename")); //got exception here, ResponseString null
                txtStatus.Text = ResponseString.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = new MessageDialog(ex, "Sorry, we got some error"); //...
            }
        }
```

I'm also try use `System.Net` , same got exception

```
private async void dvInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/api/os/machinename");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var ResponseString = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri); //got exception here, ResponseString null
                txtStatus.Text = ResponseString.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = new MessageDialog(ex, "Sorry, we got some error"); //...
            }
        }
```

Help :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Solved]**
I must move to `Windows.Web.Http` then use `https` uri inside `http` , afterthat do pass cert/ignore that:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
var http = new HttpClient(filter);
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply it worked for me too perfectly . But It doesn't work for post methods do you have method for them too ? like reboot or running apps

Comment: Working method must have settings up cookies in header while using post method.

Comment: I found that I need CSRF-Token and etc. but don't know how to add them and what is the values

Comment: could you help please , really need your help

Comment: Hi @Ali NGame, you need to put CSRF-Token in your request Header as mention in UWP doc, CSRF-Token is copied to X-CSRF-Token field. So in request header just put X-CSRF-Token

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. My problem solved but forget to mention here . again thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this is on Mobile.  If it's on desktop or another platform, ensure you're using the correct port first.

Have you tried targeting the phone from another device? e.g. run the same app using a your phone's IP address on your PC.  It may work that way. The reason for this is [loopback protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#debugging-options), where apps are prevented from connecting to APIs on the same device as a security precaution.  You may be able to enable local loopback in your app's build options in VS, at the link posted.

Comment: Yes this is actually in Mobile. Can you simplify about this? I'm still confuse.
This is only happen in latest build (14393 | Redstone) , in previous build (10568 | threshold) everything work like charm.
I'm try to "clear the Allow local network loopback check box." still no luck.